# Can't import module from subdirectory

Tags: python, import, module, subdirectory

On a high level the structure of my project looks like this.

```
dir/
    moduleA/
            __init__.py
            file1.py
            file2.py
    main.py
```

file2.py contains some global variable that I am importing in file1.py

```
# --- file2.py schema ---

SOME_GLOBAL_VARIABLE = 1
```

.

```
# --- file1.py schema --- 

from moduleA.file2 import SOME_GLOBAL_VARIABLE

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
         self.some_attr = SOME_GLOBAL_VARIABLE   

    def run():
         print(self.some_attr)
```

When I run main.py below,which creates an instance of MyClass, the code runs without errors.

```
# --- main.py ---

from moduleA.file1 import MyClass

x = MyClass()
x.run()
```

However, when I open a open a Python console and execute the below to import MyClass from file1.py I get an import error that there is no module named moduleA.

```
from moduleA.file1 import MyClass

# (... some traceback statements)
from moduleA.file2 import SOME_GLOBAL_VARIABLE
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moduleA'
```

How is this possible when Python clearly finds moduleA/file1.py, otherwise it could not try to execute the line

```
from moduleA.file2 import SOME_GLOBAL_VARIABLE
```

What seems strange to me is that it runs without errors when I run the main.py script.

I guess this is due to my lack in understanding how Python exactly imports modules, so any help is greatly appreciated. I tried adding the **init**.py file in moduleA but this did not resolve the issue.

In case this information is of relevance, the path some_path/dir is on my PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused because of the `__package__` variable.
To see it's value, add `print(__package__)` in `file1.py` before the import.

When running `file1.py` directly, you can see that `__package__` is `None`.
But on the other hand, when running `main.py`, when importing `file1.py` (and thus running it), `__package__`'s value (in `file1.py`) is suddenly `moduleA`, which is why python is able to import `moduleA.file2`.

Comment: what changes need to be made to the code to import MyClass from the Python console without error?

Comment: @antifragile if both files are in the same directory, why not just `from file2 import SOME_GLOBAL_VARIABLE` ?